# Python possible path finding

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, path-finding

I have a question about finding all possible paths from Python. I was given cities and paths of each cities. Paths are:

```
B:C D F G A M N O
C:E G H
D:F H J N O
F:G M
G:A M
A:K N
L:N
H:I A M
I:K M N
J:K
E:A K O
K:N O
```

And cities are: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O.

However each city traveler starting from one of the cities can go maximum 3 steps and each city has multiple arrows branching to other cities so that lets say Traveler starting from C can reach all these cities {’E’, ’G’, ’H’, ’A’, ’K’, ’N’, ’O’, ’M’, ’I’}.

I thought something like that, since sets store same value only once lets say city C has paths through E,G,H and also these cities has paths through other cities so that set should keep all the paths of C and its components. I know I need to use dictionaries, sets and lists but could not construct an algorithm for it.

Comment: You should show what you already tried; Stackoverflow isn't a code service where you merely would have to ask. We can help you but not do the job for you.

Comment: First devise or find an algorithm that would solve the problem without worrying too much about data-structures, then attempt to implement it using whatever facilities are available in the programming language you're using. Although it's not the best article because it focuses too much on data-structures, see [_Search Algorithms_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm) for some ideas.

Comment: I am not asking for a code or doing the job for me..I am new in Python and i could not solve the problem so that i asked for a possible hint or direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find minimal path between two cities ?

If yes,then look for **[Breadth First Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)**. 
For this ,you need to construct [Adjacency List](https://algocoding.wordpress.com/2014/08/24/adjacency-list-representation-of-a-graph-python-java/) or [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)

Comment: Not really..it is arrowed graph question so that each city has multiple ways to other cities and i have to list all cities for a starting city which traveler can go in 3 steps.It is like for instance if city A has a way to B so B should be in a list but B has a possible way to C(but A does not have direct way to C) then C also should be in A's list.But maximum 3 steps are allowed. But Thank you very much your post was helpful :)

Comment: I don't think how arrowed graph is a problem . BFS will give u all cities which are at max 3 distance. U just slightly need to modify BFS code,for ex: if nodes exceed 3 distance ,then break. 


Are you trying to find all paths or minimal path between nodes?